# View column headers in Elasticsearch's "sense"

Tags: elasticsearch, sense, elasticsearch-marvel

I am new to using Elasticsearch and I am using the [marvel](https://www.elastic.co/products/marvel) development console to run sense queries.

When I run a query (`GET _cat/indices`) I see the results, but I do not see column headers. How can I view the column headers using sense/marvel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this: `GET /_cat/indices?v` (adding `?v` and this works for other commands, as well, not only this one).